# LLVM compiler-rt i386 target on x86_64 platform

Tags: llvm

I have been building LLVM and clang 3.8 using svn for some time now. I started using git (this is not the cause of the problem) today and an error interrupted the build process that I have seen before. When make is trying to build the i386 sanitizer library it fails. I was able to disable building the sanitizers in ccmake by setting COMPILER_RT_BUILD_SANITIZERS to OFF. I would prefer to disable building the i386 target altogether. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

compiler-rt needs to be built out of tree. This is done so that it can be compiled with the newly built clang. 
This process will only build the supported architecture, x86_64 in my case.
The following example uses the default install prefix (/usr/local)
to specify the location of llvm-config.
Once LLVM is built, change the directory to where you want compiler-rt
then:

svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk compiler-rt

mkdir build

cd build

cmake ../compiler-rt -DLLVM_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/bin/llvm-config

make

make install